# copy to void* pointer

Tags: c, copy, void-pointers

I have a function `getData(void* data)`
which should copy to data some internal calculated values
for example `int r = getRadius();`
r should be copied to data ,and is such a way returned from function getData
what is the correct way to do it?
I tried `*(int*)data = r;`
but I am not sure this is a best solution.

Comment: `*(int *)data = r;` is perfectly fine, if you know the type of the memory referenced by `data` in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `void*` pointers in the first place?

Comment: this is an API of my system - nothing to do about it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are certain that the memory referenced by the void pointer is an int, then you can be confident in

```
*(int *)data = r;
```

However a better general solution is:

```
memcpy(data, &r, sizeof(int));
```

This way you don't have to worry about byte alignment or other potential gotchas.

Comment: What kind of byte alignment gotcha is associated with `*(int *)data = r;` (that is *not* associated with the `memcpy()`)?

Comment: @Alok, if `data` begins at a memory location not divisible by `sizeof(int)` (or more specifically, the alignment of int data) that code is undefined. `memcpy()` works without any alignment.

Comment: @Dave, the `memcpy()` call might be well-defined, but I am wondering what use will it be if `data` is not properly aligned for `int`?

Comment: That really depends on how you're using data. If it's tightly packed, for (e.g) network transport, you'll be dealing with unaligned data.

Comment: @alok, `getData` should take care of itself, and avoid assumptions about alignment of `void *`. Whether any callers actually have bad alignment, and whether they deal with it properly (maybe by using `memcpy` themselves), is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a good way to do it, with the API you show. dbeer's solution certainly works, but the API itself is problematic.

If the function returns a radius, which is an integer, the output parameter should be `int *`. 
I guess it isn't that simple though. The real function is more likely something like `getData(int what, void *data)`, where values of `what` determine the type of data.
Such an API is not good, because it prevents the compiler (and you, when reading the code) from checking types properly.

But if you wish to stick with this API, at least add a size parameter, and verify it before writing to `data`.